# Workflow for placing winter jacket over clothing

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have created a character with clothes using Makehuman and found a matching jacket on Sketchfab. What is the workflow so that the jacket sits neatly on top of the clothes and the clothes don't show through?
The jacket is from here- https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/1830s-frock-coat-unbuttoned-bb2d52721c394447904afa41f70ca56c
There is no cloth simulation or modifiers - everything is still as imported apart from resizing. The clothes underneath are just part of the regular mesh.

thanks Ivan
[image: My character with clothes showing through jacket]

Comment: Are you using cloth simulation for the jacket? are the clothes underneath cloth simulation or just part of the regular mesh? Can you [edit] the question to add more details of your object / mesh / modifiers setup?

Comment: Manually tweaking it in sculpt mode paired with the Cloth filter and collision modifier on the body could probably work.

Comment: In the end, I found it easier to make a new jacket using Blender by following the tutorial below. The tutorial is basically what Throndronis suggested  above. "How To Make A Simple Dress Cloth Simulation" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=777lDnaUAVY

Comment: Also this tutorial helped me a lot - How To Create & Rig Clothing: Blender 2.93 Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKBONVoHSdA